# How to make Dummies with R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to forecast the daily electricity market price, with a dataset of 3 years before of daily prices, and we want to correct some seasonal effect because we cannot predict the prices, we want to do a dummy to diferentiate everyday of the week, like everymonday, everytuesday and so on.

Can someone explain me how to make dummies in R in order to diferentiate the days on the week? my dataset is daily price, with dates. Thank you so much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do that, in R, you can use `as.factor()` to treat a variable as categorical:

```
set.seed(784)
week <- sample(1:7, 50, rep=T)
y    <- rnorm(50)

# To treat week as a factor:
m1 <- lm(y ~ as.factor(week))
summary(m1)
```

Results:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        0.3148     0.3417   0.921    0.362
as.factor(week)2   0.2059     0.5029   0.410    0.684
as.factor(week)3   0.3623     0.5293   0.684    0.497
as.factor(week)4  -0.1308     0.4678  -0.280    0.781
as.factor(week)5   0.6916     0.4678   1.478    0.147
as.factor(week)6  -0.3285     0.4832  -0.680    0.500
as.factor(week)7  -0.6165     0.4555  -1.353    0.183
```

However, if you insist, you can use this command to make dummies:

```
# To manually make dummies:
sun <- (week==1)
mon <- (week==2)
tue <- (week==3)
wed <- (week==4)
thu <- (week==5)
fri <- (week==6)
sat <- (week==7)

m2 <- lm(y ~ mon + tue + wed + thu + fri + sat)
summary(m2)
```

The results are the same:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.3148     0.3417   0.921    0.362
monTRUE       0.2059     0.5029   0.410    0.684
tueTRUE       0.3623     0.5293   0.684    0.497
wedTRUE      -0.1308     0.4678  -0.280    0.781
thuTRUE       0.6916     0.4678   1.478    0.147
friTRUE      -0.3285     0.4832  -0.680    0.500
satTRUE      -0.6165     0.4555  -1.353    0.183
```

You may also want to check [how to treat dates in R](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/dates.html), for instance, you can extract the day of the week using `weekdays()`:

```
x <- as.Date('3/20/2014',format='%m/%d/%Y')
weekdays(x)
```

Results:

```
"Thursday"
```

Answer (score 2):

In R it is seldom the case the you need to compute standalone derived variables for models.  Dummies are create automatically when a `factor` variable is included in a model formula.  Cross-products are created when a formula has * or : in it.  Simple transformations are made symbolically in a formula.  So to answer your question, depending on the modeling functions you are using, create a `factor` variable for day of the week.  For long-term time effects things like regression splines or periodic splines are often helpful.